# I need to know how long the user has been idle

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm currently using `LayoutUpdated` on the `RootVisual` member of the `Application` object, but that isn't catching absolutely everything (for instance, it doesn't catch a `Panorama` control switching between `PanoramaItems`, nor does it catch taps on the `ApplicationBar`).

Is there some other way to query the OS to find out how long it has been since the last time the user interacted with the device?